# ggplot on datatable string column error

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

Could someone tell me why the second ggplot fails? How can I change a string column in data table and use ggplot?

```
dt = data.table(name = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), value = 1:3)
ggplot(dt) + geom_point(aes(x = name, y=value)) # this works
dt[, name := lapply(name, function (x) substring(x, 2) )]
dt
   name value
1:   aa     1
2:   bb     2
3:   cc     3
ggplot(dt) + geom_point(aes(x = name, y=value)) # now fails

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need `lapply` here

```
dt[, name:= substring(name, 2)]
```

Now, the `ggplot` code should work.

By using `lapply`, we are creating a `list` with 3 elements instead of a column with 3 elements

Comment: thanks. That works. But I'm a bit confused again. After data.table accepts it as its column, why/how can it be different?

Comment: @jf328 Please check the `str(dt)` with your method and my method.  You may need `unlist` to wrap if you are using the `lapply`, but `substring` is vectorized, so you don't need `lapply`